# How do I give another player a vehicle without using exploits in Grand Theft Auto 5?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-online

We have a crew with a number of cashed up higher level players, and a bunch of destitute beginners. To help the beginners along we'd like to give them some of our (modified) crew vehicles.

When I Googled how to do this I could only find people recommending using an exploit to transfer (duplicate?) vehicles. I'm trying to keep clean and not use exploits so is there a proper way to do this?

Comment: Is there a way? I doubt. Hope next update of GTA will have shared crew garage and cars.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best thing to do is to steal a normal car from the street, then mod it without adding a tracker or insurance, then give the modded car to the player to insure and add a tracker to. It will then become their vehicle and retain the mods.

Comment: Yes, we've used this method. Pity it doesn't work on high end cars.